# ".ant does not exist" error building Aibu

Tags: java, macos, ant

I succeeded in building CoffeeShop (https://github.com/lukacu/coffeeshop) using Ant. However, I am unable to build [Aibu](https://github.com/votchallenge/aibu), an image sequence annotator.

```
pc-194-6:aibu June$ ant
Buildfile: /Users/liangjun/Documents/aibu/build.xml
```

**ivy:**

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/liangjun/Documents/aibu/build.xml:13: /Users/liangjun/.ant does not exist.
```

Comment: Just a guess but the build routines may be looking for different ant locations. Can you try "which ant" and also search for ant binaries to see what ant locations you have on your machine?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem building a jar using `ant build` .
I "solved" it by `mkdir ~/.ant/lib`
and reran `ant compile jar`
and it ran successfully.

Seems a bit tacky :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
<fileset dir="${user.home}/.ant/" includes="*.jar"/>
```

line in build.xml file.

This is where the build process looks for Ivy installation files. It seems that they are not in this directory...

Look at the [Ivy installation doc](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/install.html) :

> If you want to use Ivy only in your ant build scripts, and have an internet connection when you build, you can download Ivy from this site and use the downloaded version automatically, using this simple build snippet:

```
<condition property="ivy.home" value="${env.IVY_HOME}">
  <isset property="env.IVY_HOME" />
</condition>
<property name="ivy.home" value="${user.home}/.ant" />
<property name="ivy.jar.dir" value="${ivy.home}/lib" />
<property name="ivy.jar.file" value="${ivy.jar.dir}/ivy.jar" />

<target name="download-ivy" unless="offline">

    <mkdir dir="${ivy.jar.dir}"/>
    <!-- download Ivy from web site so that it can be used even without any special installation -->
    <get src="http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.install.version}/ivy-${ivy.install.version}.jar" 
         dest="${ivy.jar.file}" usetimestamp="true"/>
</target>

<target name="init-ivy" depends="download-ivy">
  <!-- try to load ivy here from ivy home, in case the user has not already dropped
          it into ant's lib dir (note that the latter copy will always take precedence).
          We will not fail as long as local lib dir exists (it may be empty) and
          ivy is in at least one of ant's lib dir or the local lib dir. -->
    <path id="ivy.lib.path">
        <fileset dir="${ivy.jar.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>

    </path>
    <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml"
             uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="ivy.lib.path"/>
</target>
```

Don't forget to publish the coffeeshop artefact in your local cache with the command :

```
ant publish-working
```

Before building the aibu project.

Comment: It seems you are right, but it still does not work after i installed ivy. No idea why this path is problem. And i tried to change the path to ant lib and ivy lib, neither works

Comment: Response completed.